# Why does my Outlook 2013 constantly get out of sync with my mail server?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sync

Fairly frequently, my Outlook 2013 gets its `unread` count out of sync with what's actually `unread` (we use Exchange). I can log on through OWA and clear these out, but it gets annoying because this happens pretty much every day. I do get a ton of email, most of which is filtered throughout my Outlook (to the tune of around 1,000 emails a day, with around 20 inbox rules setup). Could the frequency of emails cause this issue? Sometimes I do get a bulk of 5-10 emails all at once (e.g., if a service fails to start on a remote server, I might get 10 notifications, one for each service). I seem to have noticed this happening when I get several at once, but I haven't tested that theory really.

Sometimes the `unread` emails never even make it to my Outlook.

I don't think the amount of email is the problem. No one else on my team seems to have the same issue.

I've tried repairing my .ost file, recreating my .pst, and I've even had IT re-image my box. This problem persists unfortunately. The best answer I get from IT now is "try repairing your .ost. Again."

I'd really like to know why this happens, so that maybe I can help troubleshoot what's going on.

Comment: How exactly did you repair your .OST? The best way is to just delete it and let Outlook to create a new one automatically.